# AGPL, and converted code

Tags: agpl-3.0

Say I convert an AGPL-licensed library from Java to Kotlin using the IntelliJ code conversion functionality, and change the code from there. Can I then use this converted library in my closed source commercial project without violating the AGPL license?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, no.  Machine translation doesn't change the licensing terms on a work any more than converting a Hollywood film from .avi to .mp4 strips the copyright and permits redistribution.

So the machine-translated version is just as AGPL-covered as the original.  You then modify it, making a derivative work, which is required by AGPLv3 ss6 and 5c to be distributed under the terms of AGPLv3.  Proprietary, closed-source redistribution would violate that.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely no. The license is not rendered void simply because you take a programme and translate it into another language; translating existing source code into another language is similarily a derivative of the original work as is adding any feature or other alteration.

See also the [license text](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html) which reads

> A "covered work" means either the unmodified Program or a work based
>   on the Program.

In essence this is the same question as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151515/rewrote-gnu-gpl-v2-code-in-another-language-can-i-change-a-license) some time ago concerning GPL v2. However... IANAL.